# Combine multiple ajax call to one ajax call - Sorting / Paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let say I have data table which shows
 1. Emails
 2. Docs
 3. links

I am using three different APIs calls to show all these in one list with sorting / paging / searching etc.

```
result = api/getEmails
result1 = api/getdocs
result2 = api/getlinks
```

How can I display all three lists in one datatable with server side paging and sorting?

The problem is paging and sorting - according to all three APIs.

I did it with client side, fetched all data from 3 APIs and pass it to Jquery Datatable which then handle sorting/paging, but when data count increase the page get stuck.

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Instead of nested callbacks you might consider using promises here

Comment: @Geeky, thanks, but the problem here is sorting and paging,  let say 10 record per page, how can I divide the data upon sorting.

Comment: Agreed. I'd take a look at [this introduction to Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and this article on [`Promise#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Look into a already promisified api. Introducing the new [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) ajax api

Comment: Are these APIs yours? They fetch data from a database? If so, why not pass this responsability to the DBMS?

Comment: no, this is sharepoint APIs :(

Comment: how about lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each api call can be added as a promise like below:

```
var Promise = require('promise') // you need to get the npm library


// getAPI is your ajax call
function getApi(params, callback) {
  // make ajax and use callback on the result
}

var promises = [];

// create promise - run this as many times as you need
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    getApi(params, function (result) {
      // you can also add error handling of course
      resolve(result)
    })
})
promises.push(promise);

// resolve all promises in the array, refer to the docs here
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

new Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
  // results is an array of all the results in your promises array 
  // in the order you put them in
});
```